# ng-bootstrap Open on focus input field css not working

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-bootstrap, typehead

I have used ng Typeahead 
[Open on focus](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)  input , my conflict is that they are using `bootstrap-4` but I have used `bootstrap 3` for my project  , bootstrap 3 for that Open on focus is not working properly ,any one know how to make that work on bootstrap 3?

**html**

```
<input
  id="typeahead-focus"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  [ngbTypeahead]="search"
  (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
  (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
  #instance="ngbTypeahead"
/>
```

[stackblitz code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jc9nks)

Comment: stackblitz is working

Comment: @Chellappan stackblitz is working, but css not working, can you please check it

Comment: i think ng-bootstrap only support bootstrap4 check this https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below css in your style.css and your item will shown good as example :

```css
.dropdown-item {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
 clear: both;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #212529;
 text-align: inherit;
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0
}

.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
 color: #16181b;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #f8f9fa
}

.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #007bff
}

.dropdown-item.disabled,
.dropdown-item:disabled {
 color: #6c757d;
 background-color: transparent
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
 display: block
}

.dropdown-header {
 display: block;
 padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: .875rem;
 color: #6c757d;
 white-space: nowrap
}
```

Comment: I have use your stackblitz and put above css in style.css and it is working fine and display proper tags.